# How to add time part in database (sqlserver) asp.net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In a asp.net core MVC application, we got a DateTime field LastUpdated. In sqlserver the type of the field is a datetime. If we set the time (and date) in the database, the information is showed correctly, but after an upate the time part is always set to zeros. Code looks like:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

object.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
context.Update(object);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the value set correctly in the `object`? And what kind of object is `context`?

Comment: Yes, the value looks correct, all other values (strings, currencies, etc.) are stored correctly. LastUpdated is also stored, but just the date part.

Comment: The code here alone will work. The problem is either the database column type somehow got changed or there's some other code at play that's trimming the time portion.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the database type is changed from Date to DateTime (some days ago), without the desired effect (as we detect now).

Comment: Well, I believe that all is clear now, could be good if the person who put me a down vote revert it :-)

Answer (score 1):

The database type was Date, is changed to DataTime, BUT changes were made by hand, and we missed:

```
entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdated).HasColumnType("date");
```

which should be:

```
entity.Property(e => e.LastUpdated).HasColumnType("datetime");
```

ChrisPratt, and others, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

reading your c# code, I believe that the problem is basically the use of the UTC function, because in your table the datatype is datetime and not datetimeoffset, otherwise, in C# you are trying to send it UTC data, only to test my recomendation is to change it to

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

object.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
context.Update(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the Now makes no difference. Now and UtcNow both return a DateTime.

Comment: a quick way of confirm is simply add a formatted date to confirm if the problem is inside the assignation in the LastUpdated property.

Comment: SQL Profiler shows that the time part is NOT supplied: [LastUpdated] = @p8, @p8='2019-03-15'

Comment: good point, have you tested both cases in SQL Profiles with DateTime.Now and DateTimeNowUTC and formatted harcoded value? Test these 3 options